# Sufficient and necessary conditions for a certain measure to be sigma finite

Tags: measure-theory

If $\mu$ is a sigma finite measure on a measurable space $(X,\Omega)$, can we give sufficient and necessary conditions for a measurable function $f \colon X \to [0,\infty]$ such that the measure $\nu \colon \Omega \to [0,\infty]$ defined by $\nu(A) = \int_{A} f d\mu$ is sigma finite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that $f$ takes values in $[0,\infty)$ this measure is always sigma finite. Choose sets $A_n$ such that $X=\cup_n A_n$ and $\mu (A_n) <\infty$ for all $n$. Now let $A_{nm}=A_n \cap \{x: f(x) \leq m\}$. Then  $\cup_{nm} A_{nm} =X$ and $\nu(A_{nm})=\int_{A_{nm}} fd\mu \leq m \mu(A_n) <\infty $ for al $n,m$. Hence $\nu$ is sigma finite.

Comment: +1.  And if $\mu\{x : f(x) = \infty\} > 0$, then $\nu$ is not sigma-finite.

Comment: @GEdgar Right. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

I think $f \in L^{1}(\mu)$ should be enough.  It will certainly be sufficient as far as what is necessary I suggest looking at the Radon Nikodym Theorem.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Indeed, $f \in L^1(\mu)$ is exactly the condition for $\nu$ to be finite.

Comment: of course, thank you